# How to build Felix compatible OSGi bundles with Tycho?

Tags: osgi, equinox, apache-felix, tycho

I'm trying to build OSGi bundles for use in both Equinox and Felix.
Some of my bundles use javax.* packages, for example javax.net.

The JRE supplies that package, no problem there, it works in both frameworks.

Felix requires me to import that package in the MANIFEST.MF:

```
Import-Package: javax.net
```

It makes sense, as only java.* packages should be included implicitly.
For some reason Equinox is fine either way, it seems to magically find them anyway.

My problem comes when I build with Tycho. 
The Tycho build fails when I add that Import-Package:

> ```
> Resolution errors:
>    Bundle com.dexels.mybundle - Missing Constraint: Import-Package: javax.net; version="0.0.0"
> ```

So in a nutshell: Without import package Felix fails, with it Tycho fails.

I'm aware of this [kind of workaround](http://blog.meschberger.ch/2008/10/osgi-bundles-require-classes-from.html) using a system bundle fragment, but really hope that I won't need to resort to this.

Is there a way to add these packages to Tycho?

Can I use something like org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra?

Thanks, Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment header with a JDK that provides this package, tycho should be able to resolve the package.

you may run into https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371565

If so, you will need tycho 0.15.0, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.15

Comment: Great, works like a charm! I did need to upgrade to 0.15.0-SNAPSHOT. Thanks a bunch, Jan